# Python - Text widget from tkinter in ttk

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I noticed that the Text widget from tkinter is not present in the ttk widgets.
I'm using the ttk instead of tkinter because its interface suits better.
And I need Text widget because it has multiple lines unlikely the Entry widget.
Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: ttk is not a replacement for tkinter. It's more like an expansion pack. You can't use just ttk, you will have to use vanilla tkinter for many things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the tkinter text widget. tkinter and ttk are designed to work together.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, diferents look and feel in the same window is not usual. But if there isn't any other choise...

Comment: @ViníciusGabriel: what "look and feel" do you think a ttk text widget would give you? A text widget is mostly just a big rectangle with text. What do you expect to be different?

Comment: The same diference between Entry from tkinter and Entry from ttk.

Comment: @ViníciusGabriel: so, just the border? I don't have a system I can try it out on (linux ttk widgets don't look much different from tkinter widgets), but you can probably get the look you want just by packing a borderless text widget inside a `ttk.Entry` widget so that you see the entry widget border.